# Laravel: Find all posts made by a user using name field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4

I want to fetch all posts made by a user by matching the `name` of the user from the route url using Eloquent
My User.php has relationship as follows

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

My Post.php model has following relationship:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

my route is like following:

```
Route::get('/users/{name}', 'UsersController@show');
```

I know if I want to fetch all posts by a user I need to do something like this

```
public function show($name) {
    $user = User::find(1);
    $posts = $users->posts()->get();
    return view('users.show', compact('posts'));
}
```

but I want to find the user based on the name field in the database and not the id
I cant use `->posts()` if I use `where` like `Users::where('name', $name)->posts()->get();` , It throws error.
  
How do I fetch all posts of a user by matching his name in database with eloquent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `whereHas()`:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('user', function($q) use($name) {
    $q->where('name', $name);
})->get();
```

Or you can do this:

```
User::where('name', $name)->first()->posts()->get();
```

Or:

```
$user = User::where('name', $name)->first();
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

All these options will create two queries.

Comment: Ohh, so i should have chained the `first` mothod to where. That was missing. Thank you so much.